# Unquoting argument in macro definition hangs function call

Tags: elixir

I've been working through an exercise on macros (Dave Thomas' excellent [Programming Elixir 1.2](https://pragprog.com/book/elixir12/programming-elixir-1-2), chapter 21) and I've hit a bit of a bump in my understanding of what's happening. I have two modules, `Tracer` and `Test`, where `Tracer` redefines the `def` macro to insert call and response logging as follows:

```
defmodule Tracer do
  def dump_args(args) do
    args |> Enum.map(&inspect/1) |> Enum.join(",")
  end

  def dump_defn(name, args) do
    "#{name}(#{dump_args(args)})"
  end

  defmacro def({name, _, args} = definition, do: content) do
    IO.puts("Definition: #{inspect definition}")
    IO.puts("Content:    #{inspect content}")
    quote do
      Kernel.def unquote(definition) do
        IO.puts("==> call:   #{Tracer.dump_defn(unquote(name), unquote(args))}")
        result = unquote(content)
        IO.puts("<== resp:   #{inspect result}")
        result
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and `Test` uses this macro to demonstrate its use:

```
defmodule Test do
  import Kernel, except: [def: 2]
  import Tracer, only: [def: 2]

  def puts_sum_three(a, b, c), do: IO.inspect(a+b+c)
  def add_list(list), do: Enum.reduce(list, 0, &(&1 + &2))
  def neg(a) when a < 0, do: -a
end
```

When executing this, the first two functions work as expected:

```
iex(3)> Test.puts_sum_three(1,2,3)
==> call:   puts_sum_three(1,2,3)
6
<== resp:   6
6
iex(4)> Test.add_list([1,2,3,4])
==> call:   add_list([1, 2, 3, 4])
<== resp:   10
10
```

However, the third function appears to hang - specifically it hangs at `unquote(args)`:

```
iex(5)> Test.neg(-1)
```

So my question is, **what causes the call to neg to hang?** While I think I have an idea, I'd like to confirm (or refute) my understanding of why it does so.

The `when` clause in the third function changes the representation of the quoted expression that is passed to the `def` macro and I have no problems in reworking the macro to handle this. The `definition` and `content` passed for `neg` are:

```
Definition: {:when, [line: 7], [{:neg, [line: 7], [{:a, [line: 7], nil}]}, {:<, [line: 7], [{:a, [line: 7], nil}, 0]}]}
Content:    {:-, [line: 7], [{:a, [line: 7], nil}]}
```

When we reach the `unquote(args)` in `neg`, it is attempting to evaluate the `args` expression, which I believe is a list containing a call to `neg` and results in an infinite recursive loop. Is this correct? Any pointers to how I might debug/diagnose this would also be appreciated, as would links to further reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When we reach the `unquote(args)` in `neg`, it is attempting to evaluate the `args` expression, which I believe is a list containing a call to `neg` and results in an infinite recursive loop. Is this correct?

Yes, this is what that line compiles to:

```
IO.puts("==> call:   #{Tracer.dump_defn(:when, [neg(a), a < 0])}")
```

which results in infinite recursion.

> Any pointers to how I might debug/diagnose this would also be appreciated, as would links to further reading.

One way is to pass the value returned by `quote` to `|> Macro.to_string |> IO.puts`. This will print the exact code that was generated by that `quote` expression. This is exactly what I did to confirm your hypothesis:

```
defmacro def({name, _, args} = definition, do: content) do
  IO.puts("Definition: #{inspect definition}")
  IO.puts("Content:    #{inspect content}")
  ast = quote do
    Kernel.def unquote(definition) do
      IO.puts("==> call:   #{Tracer.dump_defn(unquote(name), unquote(args))}")
      result = unquote(content)
      IO.puts("<== resp:   #{inspect result}")
      result
    end
  end
  ast |> Macro.to_string |> IO.puts
  ast
end
```

This prints:

```
Kernel.def(neg(a) when a < 0) do
  IO.puts("==> call:   #{Tracer.dump_defn(:when, [neg(a), a < 0])}")
  result = -a
  IO.puts("<== resp:   #{inspect(result)}")
  result
end
```

which makes it clear why the function hangs.

---

One way to fix this would be to extract the actual name/args if the name is `:when`:

```
...
{name, args} =
  case {name, args} do
    {:when, [{name, _, args}, _]} -> {name, args}
    {name, args} -> {name, args}
  end
quote do
```

After this, `Test.neg/1` works:

```
iex(1)> Test.neg -1
==> call:   neg(-1)
<== resp:   1
1
iex(2)> Test.neg -100
==> call:   neg(-100)
<== resp:   100
100
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, your proposed fix is actually how I'd worked around it, so that gives me some confidence that I'm starting to understand what's going on!